# Bash built-ins with no manual entries

Tags: bash, manpage

Why do some bash built-ins (such as dirs, pushd or help) don't have manual entries?

Comment: try `man builtins`...

Comment: for help with bash builtins, `help dirs`

Comment: They have, what are you trying?

Comment: Close-voters: This is both clear *and* can be answered factually and objectively (and *has been*). In particular, answers explaining where the help is located clarify the organizational system used for manpages, which is the fundamental crux of this question. They also address what appears to be the fundamental need of the asker.

Answer (score 5):

They have. It is `man bash` or `man builtins`. Bash is the software so it has the manual where its commands are explained. We shouldn't have a manual for every command we can give in a software. E.g `ftp` has some same commands like `bash`(e.g `cd` ) or same command like a binary (`ls`), that would be very bad to make a manual for all of these. And I didn't talked about other shell's builtins.

Answer (score 5):

There is

```
man bash-builtins
```

they are also documented in

```
man bash
```

The reason they don't have manpages like `man help` is likely because of possible confusion with other shell's builtins or a command by the same name.

I generally find this to be adequate. Both the manpages above are rather long and hard to navigate.

```
help <command>
```

Answer (score 1):

To jump directly to the SHELL BUILTINS COMMANDS section of the bash man page, I define the following alias in my `$HOME/.bash_aliases` file.

```
alias man-builtin="man -P 'less -p ^SHELL\ BUILTIN\ COMMANDS' bash"
```